# mod_mono reboots server process every minute, on the minute, citing file changes as reason

Tags: mono, apache2, mod-mono, fedora16

Running mod_mono server 4.0 on Fedora 17, every minute, on the minute, mono reboots itself, citing file changes as the reason for rebooting, despite the fact no files have been made.

On occasion but not always, it will throw an exception during the cycling process. Sample log as follows:

```
Change: /var/www/html/mysite/script/dashboard/view
Change: /var/www/html/mysite/script/dashboard/controller
Change: /var/www/html/mysite/script/dashboard/model
Change: /var/www/html/mysite/script/dashboard/chart
Change: /var/www/html/mysite/script/dashboard
Change: /var/www/html/mysite/script
Change: Global.asax
Change: /var/www/html/mysite/script/dashboard/store
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.IO.MonoIO:GetFileAttributes (string,System.IO.MonoIOError&)
  at System.IO.MonoIO.ExistsDirectory (System.String path, System.IO.MonoIOError& error) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/MonoIO.cs:254 
  at System.IO.Directory.Exists (System.String path) [0x00014] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:202 
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorkerRequest.TryDirectory () [0x00007] in /builddir/build/BUILD/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoWorkerRequest.cs:191 
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorkerRequest.GetRequestData () [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoWorkerRequest.cs:216 
  at Mono.WebServer.MonoWorkerRequest.ReadRequestData () [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer/MonoWorkerRequest.cs:334 
  at Mono.WebServer.BaseApplicationHost.ProcessRequest (Mono.WebServer.MonoWorkerRequest mwr) [0x0000e] in /builddir/build/BUILD/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer/BaseApplicationHost.cs:114 
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoApplicationHost.ProcessRequest (Int32 reqId, System.String verb, System.String queryString, System.String path, System.String protocol, System.String localAddress, Int32 serverPort, System.String remoteAddress, Int32 remotePort, System.String remoteName, System.String[] headers, System.String[] headerValues, System.Object worker) [0x0016d] in /builddir/build/BUILD/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoApplicationHost.cs:113 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.ModMonoApplicationHost:ProcessRequest (int,string,string,string,string,string,int,string,int,string,string[],string[],object)
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.InnerRun (System.Object state) [0x0017d] in /builddir/build/BUILD/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoWorker.cs:239 
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.Run (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoWorker.cs:92 
[Tue Mar 26 14:24:02 2013] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Tue Mar 26 14:24:02 2013] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was 1
[Tue Mar 26 14:24:02 2013] [error] (104)Connection reset by peer: read_data failed
[Tue Mar 26 14:24:02 2013] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1
```

Any clues as to what is causing the problem or how to fix it would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking like a problem with my mono/fedora installation. I Stripped the site of all code, and the server still cycles. I copied the site to a freshly minted fedora17/mono install on the same hardware, copied the apache configuration file over, and the new server doesn't have the same problem.